# WORD Size and C/C++ Variables - Do Smaller Int Sizes Actually Use Less Memory?

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-alignment

I know that this is all implementation specific, but for the sake of example let's assume that for a certain modern computer:

`int` takes up a whole WORD

`short` takes up half a WORD

Will the short actually take up less memory, or will it just be stored in the first half of a WORD with unused memory in the second half? Will a C/C++ compiler ever try to pack two or more smaller variables into a single WORD, or will this space always be wasted?

Comment: It ultimately depends per compiler. But I've regularly found waste space in data segments as large as 16 bytes – for a single `char` or `short`. That's because aligned data on certain boundaries speeds up memory access.

Comment: @usr2564301 and I would say it also depends on how you instrument the compiler how to compile (optimization and such...) but to say, with more information provided in code, the compiler can generate "better" executables

Comment: it can only takes up less memory if sizeof(WORD) >= 1. That means on architectures where a char has the same size as an int then char, short and int must have the same size

Comment: if you have dynamic memory allocation (e.g. you're running in an operating system like linux or windows) then memory is allocated one page at a time (could be 4k at a time) , this adds another level of unused space - between the amount of memory you ask for and the page size.   Packing a short into half a word will often make the executable bigger and slower, so it's a trade off.  It may depend what you tell the compiler to optimise for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends a lot on usage.

1. You can usually force the compiler to optimize for space.
2. Objects are more optimally accessed when aligned to a memory boundary that is a multiple of their size (On most architectures).
   As such the compiler may inject space to get better alignment.
   This usually happens when objects of different sizes are required to be beside each other.
3. The compiler is **NOT** allowed to rearrange the order of variables in a structure (if they are in the same private/public/protected section).
4. I do not believe there are any requirements of ordering of variables in the local stack frame. So the compiler should be able to optimally pack the local variables and use all available space optimally (even potentially re-use space for POD variables or never use space if it can keep it in a register).

But if you have a structure that is using the same size objects.

```
struct X
{
    short      var1;
    short      var2;
}
```

Then most likely there will be no padding in the above structure (no guarantee but it's highly likely there is no padding).

Because of point 3 above: If you want to help your compiler optimally pack a structure then it definitely makes it easier for the compiler to order your members from largest to smallest as this makes the packing without needing padding much easier (but the standard does not impose any requirements on padding).

```
// if we assume sizeof(int) == 8
struct Y
{
    char      x;  // 1 byte;
                  // Compiler will (prob) insert 7 bytes of padding here.
                  // to make sure that y is on an 8 byte boundry
                  // for most effecient reads.
    int       y;
    char      z;  // 1 byte
                  // Compiler will (prob) insert 7 bytes of padding here.
                  // to make sure that the whole structure has a size
                  // that is a multiple of 8 (the largest object)
                  // This allows for optimal packing of arrays of type
                  // Y.
};
```

The compiler can still achieve optimal packing and fast access if you arrange the object like this:

```
struct Y
{
    int      y;
    char     x;
    char     z;
    // probably add 6 bytes of padding.
    // So that we get optimal access to objects in an array.
};
```

> for the sake of example let's assume that for a certain modern computer:

If we assume a modern good compiler like clang or g++ on normal standard architecture machine. Even if we assume not optimizing for speed.

> Will the short actually take up less memory

Yes. Modern compiler will pack objects as much as possible and would probably use only the memory required. Note: most compiler be default will optimize for speed so will maintain optimal alignment for speed so will pad if they have to (if objects in a structure that they can not re-order have different sizes).

> or will it just be stored in the first half of a WORD with unused memory in the second half?

Unlikely unless there is some requirement that the compiler must maintain. Like order of a structure.

> Will a C/C++ compiler ever try to pack two or more smaller variables into a single WORD

Yes. All the time. The default is usually. 1 Optimize for speed. 2 Optimize for size (not always mutually exclusive). You can also force modern compilers to optimize for space and pack structures without padding.

> or will this space always be wasted?

Unlikely.

Comment: Great answer. I perhaps wasn't clear in my question but I was more concerned with single variables on the stack rather than variables in structs. Would you be able to add some information about this too? Is there any kind of stack packing done by the compiler, or will both a char and an int use the same amount of memory?

Comment: @JShorthouse Add a point 4 about the local stack frame. This can be optimally packed as the variables can easily be re-ordered. And yes modern (and probably very old) compilers will pack variables of the same size in the stack frame to optimize for space (as long as they can maintain that alignment for optimal speed).

Comment: Thanks very much for your additional information on the stack. My final question is this:  you say that modern compilers will pack as much as possible, but then also that optimising for speed is prioritised before optimising for size. Are these two things not opposed to each other? I don't have a good knowledge of x86 assembly but I would have thought that reading packed data would need additional instructions (i.e. reading the whole word and then using bit shifting / and'ing to extract the required bits). Is this not the case?

Comment: @JShorthouse Reading objects of size 2 bytes usually only requires one instruction as long as the object is aligned to 2 byte boundary. Reading objects of size 4 bytes only requires one instruction as long as the object is aligned to 4 byte boundary. etc. There would be no need to shift or mask. The bit shift and mask is not required because the compiler knows that it is only using that part of word and uses the appropriate instructions that only operate on that size of object.

Comment: PS. x86 is not modern (its very ancient even compared to me). But I would gess even this old instruction set has this ability and modern instruction set I would guess are more capable.

Comment: @JShorthouse `Are these two things not opposed to each other?` There are rules that can be bent. Remember the standard only guarantees the ordering of objects in a structure within the same section. It does not impose any requirements say for potentially interleaving variables from different sections as long as their absolute order is maintained (though I don't know if any compilers go that far its a potential optimization). Also just because it is usually optimal to store on size based boundaries there may be other factors like size of overall object that could effect performance.

Comment: Ah ok, this has just clicked in my head. I hadn't considered the fact that x86 could have special instructions for only reading part of a word. Everything in your answer makes perfect sense to me now, thank you.